# ASP.NET - webmethod pagemethods not working with IIS express

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, webmethod, pagemethods

I have a legacy ASP.NET application that uses PageMethods in several webforms.

While it works ok when developing and testing with internal web server (under VS 2012), and also when deployed under IIS 7.5, it fails if I try to develop with IIS Express - the error is the request that calls the page method doesn't find it.

Rewriting all to get rid of pagemethods is not quote a solution, due to time restrictions, because it is used in a lot of places, meaning a lot of code changes, tests, etc, etc.

This prevents me to switch to VS 2013 (since VS 2013 doesn't have internal webserver any longer)

Anyone encountered this and know the cause and the solution?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? or is not being hit with IIS Express?

Comment: The web browser cannot find it (for example, the request shown in FF console is shown as Not Found

Comment: Could you post sample page method code which is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for the resurrection, but having encountered this in the last couple of days, this was the first google result when trying to resolve...

based on this document http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520479 I checked applicationHost.config and found all was in order. However, the same ExtensionlessUrl parameters were also present in the local web.config file. I removed them from there and the web methods started working!

Comment: Actually I found that, while your suggestion works for enabling webpage methods in IIS Express, it breaks the webapi DELETE and PUT actions. Any idea to make them both work in IIS express?

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me on both **IIS 7.5**(Windows 7) and **IIS 8.5**( Windows 8.1).

In **IIS Manager**, 
Go to **Application Pools** Tree node, 
Right click on your website and select "**Advanced Settings...**",
Expand "**Process Model**" tree node, **Identity** field click "**...**", 
Select "**Custom account:**", Click "**Set...**" button and enter, preferably, **USER** account credential.